# How to remove_action that's been added via a class that's hooked into Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

I'm trying to remove a Wordpress action that's been declared by Woocommerce Subscriptions in the following way:

```
class WC_Subscriptions_Synchroniser {

  public static function init() {

    add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', __CLASS__ . '::products_first_payment_date', 31 );
  }

  add_action( 'init', 'WC_Subscriptions_Synchroniser::init' );

}
```

The codex has a couple of examples for remove actions that have been declared within a class:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_action

Which I've adapted & combined in the following way without success:

```
$my_class = new WC_Subscriptions_Synchroniser;
function remove_my_class_action(){

  global $my_class;
  remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', array( $my_class, 'products_first_payment_date' ), 40 );
  remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', array( 'WC_Subscriptions_Synchroniser', 'products_first_payment_date' ), 40 );

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'remove_my_class_action', 40 );
```

I've also tried hooking the `remove_my_class_action` action with `init` but that doesn't work either.

Help please!

Comment: From memory I think actions need to be removed with the SAME priority that they are added/registered with.

Comment: @PhillHealey unfortunately that didn't work, however helgatheviking's answer using a higher priority did. cheers for the input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things... First, the `products_first_payment_date()` method is static, so you don't need to instantiate a class object in order to remove it. And second, a function needs to be removed before it is run. Therefore, I think an earlier priority on your `add_action()` should do the trick.

```
function remove_my_class_action(){
  remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', array( 'WC_Subscriptions_Synchroniser', 'products_first_payment_date' ), 40 );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'remove_my_class_action', 10 );
```